# Eliminating redundancy in Java Constructor

Tags: java

I have a constructor i'm trying to condense down in my assignment.

```
public int[] StudentIds;
public Students(int[] a) 
{
    StudentIds = a;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Students s1 = new Students(new int[] {123, 456, 789});
```

the line i'm wondering about is for the Students(int[] a) and then having to toss a into it for student ids. Is there a way to do this in the original brackets/parenthesis of Students() ? or do I have to kind of flow it out like this?

Comment: No, that's the only way. And BTW, your variable `StudentIds` should be named `studentIds` (and should be private).

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What redundancy are you trying to get rid of? The argument declaration?

Comment: @Mureinik I guess the OP would like doing as in TypeScript: `public Students(private int[] studentIds)`, which declares and initializes a property directly in the parentheses.

Comment: @Carcigenicate your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JBNizet How does it not make sense? I just realized though they this is Java and not C++ though, so my RAII comment doesn't apply.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well, new can be used anywhere, passing an array to a constructor is absolutely fine, and it doesn't cause any memory leak. Feel free to prove me wrong. But remember that Java has a garbage collector, doesn't need destructors, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet Like I said, I thought this was C++. That's what I get for trying to eat while commenting.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, Totally answered it and thanks for the tips as well. (also stack overflow is awesome I can't believed people replied so quick. I'll try not to abuse this power. ;D )

Comment: If you're willing to use a different language, but running on the JVM, and compatible with Java, try Kotlin, where you can declare your class and your constructor like this: `class Students(val studentIds: Array<Int>)`

Comment: @JBNizet Scala has a similar syntax, and likely has a larger community.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, but it's awfully complex, awfully slow to compile, much older (which explains its larger community), and has a self-destroying community. It's a matter of taste, of course, but my bet is on Kotlin and Groovy more than Scala.

Comment: @JBNizet Ahh. I found it to be a fun language, but I guess it's taste. I've never even heard of Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a variable argument specifier

```
public Students(int ... a){
      //a can be accessed like an int array
```

than you can call

```
 Students s1 = new Students(5,3,1)
```

to construct without the int[]{} call

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `...` varargs, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs)

if you'll do:

```
public Students(int... students) {
}
```

students will be assigned with an array of ints when called:

```
new Students(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there exists something like varargs parameters for methods and constructors. So, you can do like:

```
public Students(int ...a) 
{
    StudentIds = a;
}
```